# Streaming video, like youtube, vimeo etc. ? What are my FOSS options?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, broadcast, rtmp

What are my options regarding setting up a streaming video site, similar to youtube, vimeo etc., where video content can be viewed within the browser (both on desktop & mobiles), using free (mostly as in beer) and open-source (preferably) software ?

I stopped short of saying flash-video, although I think that is what I would need, but wanted to see if there are any other options.

I've already found Red5 but having read few articles about it, am concerned about the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question, because after a rigorous 12hour intense research, I believe I have the answer to my question.

The answer is that user-experience "almost" (but maybe not, exactly) similar to one had using real streaming-servers that use RTMP, RTSP, MMS etc. for streaming, can be had using something called "Pseudo-stream", or HTTP-streaming. This is how YouTube does it. To have the YouTube user-experience of skipping ahead or jumping backwards in a video, Flash streamers like JWplayer or Flowplayer, can manage with the aid of audio/video meta-data at the head of the file, which is then streamed over HTTP. This requires capabilities on the HTTP-server, which are able to read the meta-data information and interact with HTTP client to suspend, resume download of the file from random locations within the file. Youtube, apparently uses lighthttpd for this purpose.

Some of the interesting links where I found this information are:-

1. http://vipingupta.blog.com/2011/05/13/youtube-videos-streaming-or-progressive/
2. http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html

Answer (score 2):

use [kaltura](http://www.kaltura.org/) to save the pain, it takes a long time to develop this kind of thing. I've done bespoke using Centos/Red5/ffmpeg/PHP/MySQL in the past a few times and it takes upwards of 3 months with 4 developers. If you have specific questions drop me your email as a response and i'll follow up.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Alex. My requirement of FOSS is mostly driven by the economic advantage of "free" (as in beer), however the GNU Affero General Public License, mandates any solution built around it to be open-sourced, even if they are built as loosely coupled web-services. This, I cannot do because of the license limitation of other parts, and the project cannot afford commercial license.